# Limiting a sequence of ratios to a range whilst maintaining overall increase/decrease of values they are multiplying

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Sorry my maths isn't fantastic so you'll have to bear with me.

Let's say I have a ratio limit of 3.
I have a numpy array of sizes that are to be multiplied by the ratios and a numpy array of the ratios, some of which are within the limit, some of which aren't.

I need the ratios that are above the limit to be set to the limit and the ratios that are below the limit to be increased to account for the reduction of the ratios that were over the limit. The result would be the the sum of the sizes is still the same but the individual sizes haven't been altered by more than the limit

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: sizes = np.array([2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,10.0])

In [3]: ratios = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 5.0, 4.0, 0.5])

In [4]: print np.sum(sizes * ratios)
70.0
#result after limiting ratios would still be 70
```

Edit:
So in the example above the resulting ratios would be:

```
np.array([1.75, 1.75, 3.0, 3.0, 1.75])

In [4]: print np.sum(sizes * ratios)
70.0
```

The ratios that were previously above the limit have been reduced and the ratios that were below have been raised to compensate.

Comment: I re-read the question three times, and I am still not entirely clear on what exactly you want to do. Perhaps you could include the desired output from your example?

Comment: I am having a really hard time explaining this sorry. Does that edit help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def Spread_Ratios(ratios,sizes):
    if np.dot(ratios,sizes)/np.sum(sizes)>3.:
        print 'There is no solution!\n'
        return None

    if np.any(ratios>3.):
        score = np.dot(sizes,ratios)
        ratios_reduced = np.where(ratios>3.,3.,ratios)
        score_reduced = np.dot(sizes,ratios_reduced)

        delta_ratios = (score - score_reduced) / np.sum(sizes[ratios<3.])
        new_ratios = ratios_reduced + np.where(ratios<3.,delta_ratios,0.)

        return Spread_Ratios(new_ratios,sizes)
    else:
        return ratios,sizes
```

The recursive definition is necessary since it is possible that a weight below 3 (but close) is lifted above 3.

Furthermore it is possible that there exists no solution at all. This case is handled with the first `if` condition.